# Slide Menu With 2 Levels

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I'm working on a sidebar that slides out and has two levels. I have the first level slide out, then there is a link to slide out another level which pushes the first level further out. So I end up with 2 240px width menus taking up 480px of the screen when both levels are open.

I am able to get the 2 levels to slide out. The issue I am having is I can't get the first level to go out beyond the second level and it keeps being covered by it.

Fiddle > http://jsfiddle.net/ciaranhan/328n22sL/

HTML

```
 <ul class="menu menu-vertical menu-right" id="menu-s2">
 <li><button id="showRight2">Share</button></li> 
 <ul class="menu menu-vertical menu-right2" id="menu-s1"> 
   <li><a href="#">Email</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">FB</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Google+</a></li>
 </ul>
</ul>
<button id="showRight">Show/Hide Right Slide Menu</button>
```

CSS

```
.menu-right {
    right: -240px;
}

.menu-right.menu-open {
    right: 0px;
}

.menu-right2 {
    right: -240px;
}

.menu-right2.menu-open {
    right: 0px;
}
```

I tried to use this line to push the first level out beyond the second level but it is actually pushing the 2nd level out instead of the first.

```
.menu-right2.menu-open .menu-right2.menu-open {
right: 480px;   
}
```

Does anyone know how I can target the first level to go out 480px instead of the second?

Can also be viewed [here](http://labs.ciaranhanrahan.com/slide-menu/)